# How to know that file download is completed in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to enable a download button after a file download is completed. So is there a way I can get status that file download is completed either on client or server side?

Comment: What happens if I already *have* the file? Do I have to download it again, to proceed in your app?

Comment: You cannot do this with pure ASP.NET. Look into Javascript streams to get things done.

Comment: @nvoigt yes the user can redownload the file

Comment: I didn't mean *can* they. *Must* they? Because that seems what your question implies. You seem to want to make your user flow different based on whether or not I downloaded it. But you cannot really know whether I already have the file and do not need to download it any more.